# Installing Trader on Homestead and via Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, homestead

I want to install the latest version of Trader, 0.4.0 but ran in to issues as I have found it difficult to find a new post regarding this.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php

I am not a server person but know enough to be dangerous, so I thought I would ask the experts before I moved forward.

I need to install trader on my homestead, which is an older version 0.5.0 and have a Digital Ocean droplet, set up via Laravel Forge. Should I first update Homestead and would this upgrade cause me any issues, do you think?

Trader says it now works with PHP7 but I ran into issues when trying to use pear to install it.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Andy

Comment: SSH into Laravel Homestead and try https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/534 tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Will check it out.